# How to access efi partition on windows 10?

Tags: command-line, partitioning, windows-10

I am having trouble accessing the EFI partition on windows 10 I tried this method in cmd (I used Administrative privileges
):

open cmd as admin...

```
diskpart
sel disk 0
sel part 1 (efi part)
assign letter=b
exit
taskkill /im explorer.exe /f
explorer.exe
```

But it is not working since windows 10, I used this method fine on 8.1.

this picture shows the error I get when I try to access the partition

[image]

Comment: How is it "not working"? Some errors, or nothing happens after these steps?

Comment: I am able to see the mounted partition but I can't access it.

Comment: Why are you trying to access the EFI partition exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound because I have multiple operating systems, and should rename a file so I can access the other system.

Comment: Can you provide us the security information on the drive?  The error message seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: Have you also tried killing Explorer from the Task Manager and starting a new Explorer task with Admin Privileges (i.e. not from within Command Prompt)

Comment: Is the drive accessible from within the Command Prompt after the mount letter is assigned?

Comment: @pat2015 doesn't work mate, to answer your second question it is yes

Comment: Interestingly I find that the mounted EFI drive is accessible from the ‘Browse’ button from Task Manager -> ‘Run New Task’ You can then perform basic operations possible with Context Menu (Copy/Paste etc)  and even when you run other apps with Admin Privileges  e.g. Notepad.exe it can also access the drive from its file menu.
The issue seems to be  with Explorer.

Comment: @pat2015 This is enough to get my job done, thanks mate 

Comment: SInce I don't have enough reputation to post an answer: If you have > Win 10 1709, "dir \\?\SystemPartition\EFI\\"  should work. No mounting, no guessing. Admin rights required to modify.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The answer is by @pat2015 :

Interestingly I find that the mounted EFI drive is accessible from the ‘Browse’ button from Task Manager -> ‘Run New Task’ You can then perform basic operations possible with Context Menu (Copy/Paste etc) and even when you run other apps with Admin Privileges e.g. Notepad.exe it can also access the drive from its file menu. The issue seems to be with Explorer.

Comment: Upgraded to Windows 10 Anniversary edition and this permission trouble started. This workaround worked perfectly. I'm guessing doing some kind of "RUNAS" to behave as a SYSTEM user might work as well, but that's no fun. Maybe I'll do that if every other Windows update breaks my bootloader again.

Comment: Windows 10 Creators update fixed this problem.

Comment: You can also just open the cmd.exe as administrator and use the command line like the good ole dark ages.

Comment: Task Manager solution working in 2021. Using a Hackintosh while in Windows I was unable to access the EFI partition via Explorer and CMD had access denied with elevated privileges

Comment: Windows 10 w/ latest updates as of jan2023, this trick works.

Answer (score 32):

Try the following, which works in Windows 7 and 8, but I can't promise anything with 10:

1. Open an *Administrator* Command Prompt window by right-clicking the Command Prompt icon and selecting the option to run it as Administrator.
2. In the Command Prompt window, type `mountvol P: /S`. (You can change `P:` to any unused drive letter; that's arbitrary.)
3. Use the Command Prompt window to access the `P:` (EFI System Partition, or ESP) volume.

You'll need to use text-mode commands, rather than the GUI, but this method should work.

Another alternative is to use another OS. Even if you can't boot your other OS now, which you strongly imply, you might be able to use an emergency disk. An Ubuntu installation medium, for instance, should let you access the ESP pretty easily. IIRC, it should show up as a volume in the lower-left corner of the screen; or you can use the standard Linux `mount` command to mount it in any way you like.

Comment: Doesn't work mate

Comment: I tried it with a vanilla install of windows 10 1151 64 bit (i.e. not an upgrade from windows 7.). The mounting part worked fine, but the entire directory is read-only! What's the point in that? Well, it worked a bit. Do you know how to make it read-write?

Comment: This worked for me in Windows 10, recovery mode. Thanks!

Comment: I get an error mountvol P: /s
The parameter is incorrect.

Comment: Works on Windows 10 - 1903

Comment: `mountvol p: /S` works fine in admin powershell, win10. Allowing you to browse and edit the partitions files in the cli, but not explorer

Comment: It also works with other file managers like Total Commander, which can be started "as administrator". However, some files are still not readable, like the "BCD.LOG" which I wanted to see.

Comment: Worked for me on Windows 11 as well.

Comment: So I mounted as shown above, then proceeded with HackBGRT-1.5.1 command line setup (Windows Boot Logo Replacer). During one step of the install it openes up the text configuration file in notepad that the setup process internally copied to the EFI boot partition. Just out of curiousity I went to open and the P drive was accessable in the OpenFile Dialog. This was only viewable in the GUI while the setup process was running. It didn't make it viewable to windows explorer, only the OpenFile dialog that was spawned from within notepad.

Comment: This mounted... *something* on P: but I get access denied trying to access it.  Where exactly in `mountvol P: /S` are you telling it which volume to mount???  Because I've got two separate drives that have EFI partitions, and the one I want to mount EFI on doesn't have any partitions with drive letters...

Comment: How do you dismount EFI partition safely after `mountvol P: /S`? Using /d or /P?

Answer (score 11):

## Update

in Windows 8.1, Windows 10 and Windows Server starting as of 2012 R2 you can use the following Powershell oneliner for getting Read-Write access to EFI partition:

`start ((Get-Partition | ? IsSystem).AccessPaths[0])`

## Original answer

I have found more straightforward way of getting read/write access to EFI partition from Windows 10:

1. Open an *Administrator* Command Prompt window by right-clicking Start button and clicking on Command Prompt (Admin)
2. In the Command Prompt window, type `mountvol`, disregard help message in the beginning and notice the list of GUID-based paths of all volumes known to Windows, eg.:

[image: list of volumes' GUIDs]

3. GUID of EFI partition is one of those marked with "NO MOUNT POINT" description - in my case it was the first volume
4. type `start \\?\Volume{.......-....-....-....-...........}\` (of course replace dots with the exact GUID from step #3) and new explorer window will pop up with the contents of EFI partition and read/write access to it - voila!

[image: EFI partition in explorer]

Comment: How do one unmount the volume safely again?, the description on /P sounds destructive?

Comment: @neslekkiM   it is not get mounted, just close explorer

Comment: Once you have assigned a drive letter P to the efi partition you can exit diskpart and use the usual cmd commands like P:>dir which will list whats on P and so forth.

Comment: There is a corner case to this, where there are multiple EFI partitions present (for example, when someone attaches a second drive that contains a previous EFI partition). I believe this will not be able to differentiate between the two, with just the approach above.

Comment: @WillIAm You are right, there will be >1 objects returned by the expression. Selector to choose correct disk drive should be added. Unfortunately I do not have access to any Windows hosts to check

Comment: Why the censoring in the UUIDs? They're not credit card numbers...

Comment: Yeah, really important to sensor those classified uuids! FACEPALM

Comment: On Windows 11 does not work with EFI partition

Comment: @FranciscoZarabozo  just ignore picture, oneliner in the update works perfectly