# Mysterious new ESP drive in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

Today a mysterious new drive called "ESP (F:)" appeared on my PC. It is about 500 MB. And when I click on it, I'm told I do not "currently have permission to access this folder".

See bottom right of following image:

[image]

Is this just a bug that I needn't be too worried about?

Some others reporting the same thing at [another site](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/623097/mysterious-added-drive/).

Answer (score 4):

AKA EFI partition, apparently it was assigned a drive letter, you can remove the drive letter (set it with no drive letter) using Disk Management and it will become hidden in explorer again.

To answer the other question as why you cannot access it [see this question](https://superuser.com/questions/965751/how-to-access-efi-partition-on-windows-10)

**EDIT**: Adding the solution from the OP comments, restart the PC several times and it will disappear.

Comment: It has no letter on Disk management, but it took over my network drive in my computer.... can this partition be removed ?

Comment: It has to if Explorer shows a drive letter, no I would not remove it.

Comment: noap. Explorer has a drive letter DM hasn't. needed to boot the computer twice and it was gone.....

Comment: When in doubt reboot, reboot,reboot! Glad you solved it.

Answer (score 2):

This is the EFI Partition which contains boot loaders for the OS.  Therefore deleting it is a no-no.  Windows 10 may sometimes recover if you deleted it, but not always - it depends on your motherboard BIOS.

Normally, you shouldn't see it as it's a hidden partition, but if you can see it you can hide it again by starting an elevated command prompt and typing

```
mountvol <driveletter>: /d
```

For me, this allowed mapped network drives to be correctly mapped again from the domain where the drive letter was consumed by the ESP partition.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience this is a temporary partition used during a Windows 10 upgrade. After installation of upgrade and reboot, it should disappear.