# Window8.1, after update and suddenly appear a new drive

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1

The System drive appear after I update the window, and I unable to find the drive at the Disk Management.

How do I make the drive disappear/hide. The System drive appear after I update, and it is unable to access.

[image: The System drive appear after I update, and it is unable to access.]

[image: Unable to find the drive at Disk Management.]

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to rephrase your question as I do not really understand what your problem is. If you are talking about not being able to access the recovery partition or the EFI partition, that is intended and not a bug. Those partitions host the MBR and other stuff which you should not fiddle around with.

Comment: My question is how can I fix the SYSTEM drive that suddenly appear after update, I know that the drive shouldn't appear in there. So what I need to do to hide the file.  This is my first time ask question in here,sorry.

Comment: What you can do is the following: 1. Backup all your data 2. boot from a live cd and delete all the SYSTEM partitions and the efi partitions. WINDOWS WILL NOT BOOT ANYMORE FROM NOW ON. 3. Boot from the Windows DVD and let  Windows repair itself. 4. You may have to do that step 3 times to get back into windows.

Comment: There are numerous questions on how to remove the drive letter from your EFI partition.  Have you tried using those solutions?  Don't follow Steven's suggestion, the solution to this "problem" can be non-evasive...their solution is drastic

Comment: Remove its drive letter?  (at first i thought this was totally about the chinese icon)  http://www.disk-partition.com/diskpart/assign-drive-letter-4125.html

Comment: Maybe related to to his question... http://superuser.com/questions/1113046/mysterious-new-esp-drive-in-windows-10/1113047#comment1587495_1113047

Comment: It seem like reboot,reboot, and reboot method are working.Thanks for the helping guys.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, though after updating my BIOS. Follow the following:

1) Press Win+X and open Administrator Command Prompt.

2) Now type "diskpart" and press enter.

3) Type in "list volume" and press enter, you’ll see the drives of your computer listed.

4) Type in "select volume G" and press enter.

5) Type in "remove letter G" and press enter.

Exit and (not necessary) reboot!

Answer (score -1):

It looks like it's EFI partition, I guess that part of the question wasn't answered. Follow other answers to hide that.