# Mysterious new ESP D: drive in windows 10

Tags: windows-10

After cloning to a bigger SSD I have the normal C: drive, but I also have a new drive called ESP D drive how do I remove that drive!
I used disk-part and remove letter=D the drive disappeared..but after rebooting it just keeps coming back any suggestions.

Comment: It's EFI System Partition. See https://www.diskpart.com/articles/efi-system-partition-4348.html, https://superuser.com/questions/1113046/mysterious-new-esp-drive-in-windows-10 - web search for `ESP D: drive` brings a lot more results.

Comment: If you installed correctly, you should have 3 partitions, not drives.  One drive:  UEFI, Data, and Recovery partitions.  This is a normal install.

Comment: It keeps coming back because it's attribute flag is wrong. So Windows is properly detecting a drive and assigning a drive letter to it