# How to make EFI System Partition to show up in mountvol cammoand call

Tags: hard-drive, command-line, partitioning, efi

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad T440 running Windows 10 Pro 64bit in UEFI/GPT mode. The disk manager shows there are 4 partitions on the HDD. They are 1000MB WINRE_DRV (recovery) NTFS, 260MB SYSTEM_DRV (EFI System Partition) FAT32, 889GB Windows10_OS (C:) NTFS, and 14GB PBR_DRV (Lenovo Recovery) NTFS.

Under DISKPART, list volume command shows all these 4 volumes.
However using command mountvol in CMD shows only 3 volumes with GUID. The 260MB SYSTEM_DRV (EFI System Partition) in FAT32 format is missing. Can somebody explain it to me why? And how to make it show up with the mountvol command?

a superuser MAOIZM in Sep 3 in this link shows that he can make it happen, how
[How to access efi partition on windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/965751/how-to-access-efi-partition-on-windows-10)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following to access the ESP in Windows:

1. Open an *Administrator* Command Prompt window. (Right-clicking the Command Prompt option in the Start menu and selecting "Run as Administrator" should do this.)
2. Type `mountvol S: /S`. This mounts the ESP as `S:`. (You can change `S:` to anything you like.)

The resulting mount will be valid only within that Administrator Command Prompt window, though, which can be limiting, especially if you want to use GUI file-management tools or access the ESP from GUI programs. If there's a way to access the ESP in Windows using GUI tools, I don't know what it is.