# Recover data from EFI partition

Tags: windows-10, efi, partition-recovery

I'm using Windows 10. While installing Ubuntu I accidentally converted one of my data partitions (drive D) to an EFI system partition.

After restarting the system in Windows, I cannot access drive D. It says "D: is inaccessible".

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can play with tricks from here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/4937caeb-e23e-4796-a610-caf4c39d9c4f/convert-efi-partition-to-ntfs?forum=w7itproinstall

but it's destructive.

Try this first: [How to access efi partition on windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/965751/how-to-access-efi-partition-on-windows-10)

just in case that something survived. If it did, copy & reformat.