# Windows 7 boot loader on a new drive?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, multi-boot, bootloader

We had a SATA3 drive that was performing poorly and making noise, and installed Windows 7 onto a new drive.  The install went well, but left the bootloader on the old drive, and so I could not remove it; Windows treated it as a multi-boot system with a new boot option on the new disk.   Everything worked, so I figured I'd have time to fix it.  Well, the old drive died a few weeks later and now I have no idea how to address this.

How can I instruct the PC to boot to the new disk, when there isn't a bootloader present on it?  Do I need to reinstall Windows from scratch?  From looking at the board specs, it supports UEFI, I am unsure if this is relevant.

Thanks!

EDIT: I've been able to get the original boot drive running.  That drive has a 100MB EFI partition, can I simply resize the new disk to add a new partition at the beginning of the drive, and copy it there?

Comment: Reinstall windows with the old drive disconnected.

Comment: I think you can install the bootloader onto the new drive booting from an external DVD/ISO.

Comment: If I reinstall Windows with the old drive disconnected, will it update the bootloader only or will it completely reinstall the OS (Programs etc.)?

Comment: Boot from external USB/DVD, go to command line and then use **bcdboot** command to recreate boot files.  See here for example https://www.tweakhound.com/2012/11/13/how-to-fix-the-windows-bootloader/

Comment: @mikewaters You ever connect to my chat room link? Read over answers here: https://superuser.com/questions/965751/how-to-access-efi-partition-on-windows-10 about getting the detail from that partition since you can access the drive that contains it. See how it's pointing to the volumes, etc. in it's configs.

Comment: Mike Waters has left the building!!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Boot from your Win7 installation media
2. Choose Windows 7 Setup Language and Other Settings
3. Click on the Repair Your Computer Link
4. Choose Your Windows 7 Installation
5. Choose the Startup Repair Recovery Tool

This process should locate your installation and make a new Windows boot loader that points to it.

SOURCE:
https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-perform-a-startup-repair-in-windows-7-2626170