# Windows EFI Partition Not Editable

Tags: windows, partitioning, security, windows-explorer, efi

Based on the following question:
[How to access efi partition on windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/965751/how-to-access-efi-partition-on-windows-10)

I have been unable to open the EFI partition by running the commands below:

```
mountvol

start \\?\Volume{xxxxxxx-ec0e-43ab-82ce-xxxxxxxxx}\
```

[image]

It says to look on the security tab, but upon opening the properties for the EFI partition there is no security tab!

Any suggestions would be helpful.

**EDIT**

Thanks for the replies. So I ran the following command to mount the drive.

```
mountvol S: /s
```

Then the following command to open up either Explorer++ or notepad.exe

```
"C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\Explorer++.exe"

notepad.exe
```

However, when finding the S:\EFI\Boot\bootx64.efi file and trying to copy it over to the C:\ drive I am getting the following error:

[image]

**EDIT 2**

Using notepad.exe or Explorer++ does not work for copying files to the C:\ drive. However, I was able to use the following command to copy files over from the EFI partition to the C:\ drive.

```
copy S:\EFI\Boot\bootx64.efi C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\
```

Comment: There isn't a security tab because the EFI partition is FAT32.  You did issue that command as an Administrator in an elevated prompt?  Did you try running the command `start ((Get-Partition | ? IsSystem).AccessPaths[0])` instead?

Comment: Use the  DISKPART commands ( from that original question)  in Admin Command prompt to mount the EFI partition to a drive letter. Then use a freeware called Explorer++  https://explorerplusplus.com/download to seamlessly access EFI partition.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same issue using `start ((Get-Partition | ? IsSystem).AccessPaths[0])`.

You can however mount the EFI partition using `mountvol s: /s` from Administrator command prompt (changing `s:` to another letter if you wish).

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> mountvol s: /s
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> ls s:                                                                                           

    Directory: s:\


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
da----       01/12/2019     09:47                EFI
d-----       15/10/2019     16:08                temp
-a----       26/11/2019     09:31        6285696 vmlinuz-linux
-a----       21/11/2019     09:24        3120640 intel-ucode.img
-a----       26/11/2019     09:31        9709791 initramfs-linux.img
-a----       31/05/2019     17:19            503 refind_linux.conf
-a----       19/04/2019     13:45             87 keybindings.txt
-a----       15/11/2019     07:15           4119 BOOTLOG
-a----       05/07/2019     21:17       15552054 screenshot_001.bmp
-a----       05/07/2019     21:17       15552054 screenshot_002.bmp
-a----       26/11/2019     09:31       29906590 initramfs-linux-fallback.img


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> mountvol s: /d
```

As the volume is mounted in administrator context it will not be visible in Explorer nor non-administrator command prompt.

You can however then run programs as administrator to access files on EFI partition.  For example *notepad.exe* running as Administrator can see `s:` :

[image: Screenprint]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried your method but was unable to copy files over using Notepad. See my edit in the main post for more info.

Answer (score 0):

The **official** way of mounting it is `mountvol (drive letter) /S`. You may then access it via CMD (administrator) or for a GUI you can download [Explorer++](https://explorerplusplus.com/) for free. Make sure to run it as administrator. To unmount the volume run `mountvol (same drive letter as before) /D`. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried your method but was unable to copy files over using Explorer++. See my edit in the main post for more info.

Comment: Did you run Explorer++ as administrator? Did you run `mountvol S: /S` as administrator?

Comment: Yes, please see the edit that I made to the original question. When opening explorer++ I ran the following command in the Admin CMD window ""C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\Explorer++.exe"" to open Explorer++.

Comment: I did. First, try opening Explorer++ through File Explorer, then going into the S: partition, locating bootx64.efi, (obviously) right-clicking it, selecting “Copy”, go back to the C: drive, click “Paste”. Alternatively, you can run “copy S:\EFI\Boot\bootx64.efi C:\path\to\folder”, without quotes. \path\to\folder is the folder you want to copy it to, if it contains spaces, put quotes around C:\path\to\folder.

Comment: Made a edit, was able to copy the file using CMD command but still unable to copy using notepad or Explorer++. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution I have posted [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1609424/how-to-edit-files-in-efi-partition-on-windows-10/1609425#1609425).

It should work with any program that can open a file directly from the command prompt