# How to edit files in EFI partition on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-access, efi, editing

I want to edit my Clover boot entries from within Windows 10 to add back my linux mint listing in clover. I could boot my Linux Mint from clover until I was forced to reinstall my Linux mint instance (moved to Linux Mint 20 [Ulyana], at which point it disappeared from Clover's boot menu items list. As I can no longer access my Linux Mint installation, i find my self stack i Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I found a few solutions from right here on stackexchange.com.

I found an answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/662823/how-do-i-mount-the-efi-partition-on-windows-8-1-so-that-it-is-readable-and-write) that kinda helped me. Basically you need to do this

```
diskpart
list disk
select disk 0
list partition
select partition 1
assign letter=b
exit
```

after which you can open any editor or application to edit your `config.plist` at (according to this example post) `b:\EFI\CLOVER\config.plist` (assuming that's where in the EFI partition you have installed clover) by running *notepad* or any other editor like *VS Code* like so

```
notepad b:\EFI\CLOVER\config.plist
```

or

```
code b:\EFI\CLOVER\config.plist
```

Your changes are made when you do this.