# Different C Drive Storage Capacities in Explorer and Settings

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, storage

My C Drive is allocated to 149 GB as you can see here in Explorer
[image]

You can also see the same in Disk Management

[image]

But in Setting, it shows 223 GB as the Capacity
[image]

May I know why this is happening? Thank you!

**EDIT: I added a few more pictures to solve the conflict of answers.**

> Capacity of my SSD where C Drive is Located: 223 GB just like the Settings app said but referred it as C Drive storage.

[image]

> These are the Disks connected to my computer

[image]

> Complete window of Disk Management

[image]

> Storage of all partitions as seen on the Settings App.

[image]

> Menu Options for a Partition

[image]

Comment: Could you post a _less cropped_ screenshot from Disk Management?

Comment: @user1686 Please refer to the few more added pictures.

Answer (score 0):

The 'Storage' screen in Settings actually shows the size of the *entire* physical device that the C: volume is on (counting all non-Windows partitions as "used" space).

Comment: Thanks a lot, @user1686! I don't know how I didn't catch that.

Comment: This is wrong and untrue. Settings Storage reports partition sizes, not disk.

Comment: @harrymc: Thanks, I've just checked and it does not include unallocated space in the report. It does however include partitions that _precede_ the C: partition.

Answer (score 0):

The Settings Storage section is lumping with the C: partition all the following
partitions that don't have drive-letters, which follow the
C: partition, and this also includes unallocated space.

If you had another partition with drive-letter following C:, the size
of C: wouldn't include it.

This is a Microsoft problem/bug with the Settings Storage applet.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @harrymc! I have added a few more screenshots to prevent any confusion.

Comment: The unallocated space is said not be included in the size. But the important screenshot is the lower part of Disk Management.

Comment: I added the complete disk management screenshot as requested.

Comment: As a test, give the following partition after C: a drive-letter and see if its size changes in Settings.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the Settings app showing all the partitions.

Comment: Try my above test of giving a drive-letter to a partition after C:.

Comment: I assume you're telling me to assign a drive letter to a partition after C drive which is a 541 MB partition. I suppose those are where my bootloader files are stored hence I can't choose a drive letter for it.

Comment: Since SSDs are faster, I also did a dual boot for my Linux on the same disk. Those partitions belong to my Linux OS. Hence, I can't change any drive letter. To change the drive letter, I have to format the whole partition. Hope you understand.

Comment: You can assign a drive-letter to the EFI partition. This will preclude the following 73 GB partition.

Comment: I don't have any option to do that as you can see from the new picture I added in the edit.

Comment: See this post : [How to access efi partition on windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/965751/how-to-access-efi-partition-on-windows-10).

Comment: Are you sure it won't mess up my drive, right? Cause I am a student and cannot afford my computer to go inactive. I've done GRUB reinstalling but not sure what Win10 Bootloader is.

Comment: You may remove the drive-letter with the same [mountvol command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mountvol). This shouldn't cause any problem, just don't use the wrong drive-letter when dismounting. Don't do it if you're unsure of yourself.

Comment: I am sure I can do it correctly but I cannot even afford a 0.00001% chance of messing things up for some bug which doesn't really bug me a bit. Thanks a lot for your help! I will ping you once my exams get over when I can peacefully mess with my pc.

Comment: Good luck with your exams, then.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Harry! Kind of you 